# Doesn't save screen output properly after grep operation

Tags: linux, shell, grep

In shell, I executed the following:

```
grep -nri "\d" * | egrep -v "Created by|Licensed under|Copyright (c)|copyright  (c)" > output.txt
```

In screen output, it did get the result I wanted. I only saw the lines containing digits excluding the exact strings I specified above.

But in `output.txt`, it saved all the result I got from `grep -nri "\d" *`. The contents of `output.txt` didn't exclude the exact strings I specified above.

How do I save the screen output with the `egrep -v` command reflected as I see from my screen?

Comment: Escape `(` and `)` with a backslash.

Comment: Can you copy-paste from your terminal showing how output differs between the redirected and non-redirected case? Make sure to include prompts, commands and output.

Comment: Blind guess - in egrep try enclosing parts between '|' into '()' or try grep -Ev. But output to screen should match redirected result.

Answer (score 0):

Egrep uses POSIX extended regular expressions.  If you're using pipes (`|`) for [alternations](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html), you need this.  However, extended regular expressions also have a special use for parentheses (`(` and `)`), so those must be escaped.

See [this guide on POSIX Basic and Extended Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html) for further explanation.

Try running the below command, which escapes your parentheses:

```
grep -nri "\d" * | egrep -v "Created by|Licensed under|Copyright \(c\)|copyright  \(c\)" > output.txt
```